# How to merge multiple output from single table using talend?

Tags: talend

I have Employee table in database which is having gender column. so I want to Filter Employee data based on number of gender with three column to excel like:

[image]

I'm getting this output using below talend schema
**Structure 1**:

[image]

So I want to optimized above structure and trying in this way but I have been stuck with other scenario. Here I'm getting Employee data with gender wise but in three different file so Is there any way so that I can achieve same excel result from one SQL input file and after mapping can be get in a single output excel file?

**Structure 2** :

[image]

**NOTE**: I don't want to use same input table many time. I want to get same output using single table and single output excel file. so please suggest me any component which one is useful for me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This looks very complicated. Shouldn't you be able to get all the source data with a simple query and then simply connect a `tFileOutputExcel` to the `tSQLInput`?

Comment: i agree with @tobi6..you should try to use select month, sum(case when gender='male' then 1 else 0 end) malecount, sum(case when gender='female' then 1 else 0 end) femalecount....from databasetable group by month ...use this sql in your tSQLInput and you should be all good...else if you want to do it completely in talend you can use tUnite component to union results

Comment: @garpitmzn, Yes, I know that I'll get output with MySQL case Query in tMysqlInput directly and I already tried......I'm getting required output also with Structure 1 and you can see output above image that file is generated by talend tool.......but in structure 1, I'm using same employee table three time because I want three categories of gender column.........So My question is only that I want to optimized Structure 1, Do you have any Idea how to optimize?.......I was trying in Structure 2 and I was using tUnit component also but unable to merge...

Comment: @tobi6, I don't want to achieve this output usingMySQL case Query directly.................I want this output using talend components only............I'm learning talend tool and about MySQL Queries I know very well, even I'm doing cross check this output data is correct or not with MySQL Query only.....

Comment: with mysql case statement you dont need to refer to same table 3 times, its single sql and single tsqlinput component. otherwise in your structure#2 you have another way of splitting data into output groups in tmap and then doing agg..what problem you face if you use tUnite? also another way in your structure #2 would be to use tHashOutput to store data into memory instead of in file and finally unite this tHashInput to tunite and write to single file.

Comment: @garpitmzn, Thanks for your suggestion. I'm trying to achieve using tHashOutput.

Comment: Then the result of your SQL query is not clear to me. I am still not conviced that the preparation of the job in form of a well-structured SQL statement is achieved. I'd prepare the query so that it gives me 3 column values for months I can sum, one row for one employee, use an *tAggregateRow* to count all occurences and output to Excel.

Comment: does open studio have the tReplicate component?

Comment: @BalazsGunics tReplicate component's function is incoming schema into multiple identical output flows...My actual requirement is that I have 3 tAggregateRow and I want to merge that 3 output in a single output file(See Struture 2)................